# How to use `notifyItemremoved` in `firebaserecycleradapter`?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm using `firebase-ui` to retrieve my data from firebase. What I want to do is remove from displaying it to my `recyclerview` if the `status` is equal to `"unlive"`. I've been searching on the internet for days but can't find a solution for this.

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Hotels_Model, Adapter_HotelsHolder>(mOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_HotelsHolder holder,int position, Hotels_Model model) {

            String status = model.getStatus();
            if (status.equals("unlive")) {
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
         mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                             
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it doesn't make sense to call both `notifyItemRemoved` and `notifyDataSetChanged`. They accomplish similar goals, so you'll want to call one or the other. `notifyDataSetChanged` tells the adapter that every view should be rebound and the layout will happen as if you had just attached the adapter to the `RecyclerView`. `notifyItemRemoved` notifies the adapter that an item at a particular index was removed. This allows the adapter to perform the relevant animations to animate the removal. If you have access to the underlying list of `Hotels_Model`, you should remove all `"unlive"` models from the collection. Then you can call `notifyItemRemoved` with the relevant position(s). If there are many removals, you can use `notifyItemRangeRemoved` or `DiffUtil` to calculate all the necessary removals for you and pass that to the adapter.

Here's a sample adapter that uses DiffUtil to dispatch updates to the adapter:

```java
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

  public void updatePaths(List<String> oldPaths, List<String> newPaths) {
    DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffCallback(oldPaths, newPaths));
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
  }

  class DiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private List<String> oldPaths;
    private List<String> newPaths;

    DiffCallback(List<String> oldPaths, List<String> newPaths) {
      this.oldPaths = oldPaths;
      this.newPaths = newPaths;
    }

    @Override public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
      return oldPaths.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newPaths.get(newItemPosition);
    }

    @Override public int getOldListSize() {return oldPaths.size;}

    @Override public int getNewListSize() {return newPaths.size;}

    @Override public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
      return oldPaths.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newPaths.get(newItemPosition));
    }

  }
}
```

If it takes a long time to calculate the diff (i.e. the list is very large), you'll want to compute the diff on a background thread and post the result back to the main thread.

A side note on style, I'd recommend moving away from using underscores in class names and just using CamelCase. Underscores in class names goes against convention.

Comment: Any codes using java? Sorry i'm just a beginner can't understand a kotlin code. Thanks

Comment: Updated example to use Java instead of Kotlin.